# Summation Equivalent definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

Given the definition:

[image]

Prove Lemma 6.1.1:

[image]

However, when the proof gets to the following case, I don't understand the second "step" (marked with a red question mark).

[image]

Can you provide some clarification? As fully detailed and justified as possible, please. I tried proving Lemma 6.1.1 myself using induction but I couldn't, here's my attempt:

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Note: Here induction "runs" on $\mathbb{N}$ starting from $1$ (not $0$):

1. $a=b$
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{n=a}^{b} f(n) &= f(n)\\
   &= f(b) && \text{$n=a=b$}\\
   &= f(b) + 0\\
   &= f(b) + \sum_{n=a}^{a-1} f(n) && \text{Definition (6.1.1)} \\
   &= f(b) + \sum_{n=a}^{b-1} f(n)
   \end{align}
2. For $a<b$, we use induction over $b$,

- [Base case] For $b=a+1$,
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=a}^{b=a+1} f(n) &= f(a) + \sum_{n=a+1}^{a+1} f(n) && \text{Definition (6.1.1)}\\
  &= f(a) + \sum_{n=b}^{b} f(n)\\
  &= f(a) + f(b)\\
  &= f(b) + f(a)\\
  &= f(b) + \sum_{n=a}^{a} f(n)\\
  &= f(b) + \sum_{n=a}^{b-1} f(n) && \text{$b=a+1 \Rightarrow b-1=a$}
  \end{align*}
- [Induction hypothesis] Assume that for $b=a+k$, with $k\in \mathbb{N}$ we have that:
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=a}^{a+k} f(n) &= f(b) + \sum_{n=a}^{b-1} f(n)
  \end{align*}
- For $b=a+k$ we have:
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=a}^{b=a+k+1} f(n) &= f(a) + \sum_{n=a+1}^{a+k+1} f(n) && \text{Definition (6.1.1)}\\
  \end{align*}

From that point on I don't know what goes next, please help.

Answer (score 2):

The induction in proof 6.1.1 is on $b-a$.

The induction hypothesis would assume the lemma is true for any LHS where the the upper and lower bounds differ by $b-a-1$. This includes assuming the lemma is true for LHS like:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=a}^{b-1}f(i) &= \cdots\\
\sum_{i=a-1}^{b-2}f(i) &= \cdots\\
\sum_{i=a+1}^{b}f(i) &= \cdots \tag{*}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{b-a}f(i) &= \cdots\\
\end{align*}$$

Then your $(\color{red}?)$ line is applying one particular case $(*)$ of the induction hypothesis, where the LHS has lower bound $a+1$ and upper bound $b$:

$$
\sum_{i=a+1}^{b}f(i) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $b<a+1$}\\
f(b)+\sum_{i=a+1}^{b-1} f(i) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The summation on the RHS of the last line should have upper limits of a+k. Then you might be able to use the first term on the RHS to arrive at something that lets you use induction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).